# Loading Human Readable Hex String Private/Public Keys Using Python (Or Converting Them to Pem or ASN.1 Format)

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I have a human readable private/public elliptic curve (ecdh) key pair in a hexadecimal string. The public key is `64 Bytes` (`128 hex` characters) and the private key is `32 Bytes`.

**Question** :How can I load these into either a python cryptography key or convert them into pem or der format using python?

I can easily load a pem or der private/public key so converting them to one of those two formats should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out after more research. Python-ECDSA has functionality that allows loading the bytes of a human readable key and outputting them in either a PEM or DER format. See python-ecdsa [here](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/blob/master/src/ecdsa/keys.py).

Answer (score 0):

No one will be able to give you a concrete answer, since it will be library dependent.

Usually, EC public keys are encoded using the ASN.1 definitions from [RFC 5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480).

Comment: It doesn't have to be library dependent. Any library or code that will encode these in a PEM or ASN.1 format will do.